# Translate animation created programmatically has incorrect duration and offset

Tags: android, android-animation

Here's what needs to be done:

I have a top bar with 3 buttons. Two on the right can be pressed and nothing is interesting about them. The left one replaces all three buttons with other three. With animation: middle and right (new ones) buttons slide out from left button's position to their corresponding places, while old buttons fade out. The left button gets replaced without movement: old one fades out, new one fades in.

How this was done:

```
final Animation fadeOut, fadeIn;
Animation fadeOutWithListener;
fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.camera_top_bar_fade_in);
fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.camera_top_bar_fade_out);
final TranslateAnimation slideAnim;

slideAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -flashAutoBtn.getLeft(),
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
slideAnim.setDuration(1000L);
slideAnim.setStartOffset(0);
fadeOutWithListener = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.camera_top_bar_fade_out);
fadeOutWithListener.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        flashAutoBtn.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        flashOnBtn.startAnimation(slideAnim);
        flashOffBtn.startAnimation(slideAnim);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        flashBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        gridBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        switchCameraSideBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        flashAutoBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flashOffBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flashOnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
});

flashBtn.startAnimation(fadeOutWithListener);
gridBtn.startAnimation(fadeOut);
switchCameraSideBtn.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

How it actually works:
fadeIn/Out animations are ok - they defined in xml, have duration set to 1000 and last 1 second. With no offset.

Two translation animations work incorrectly: first, they don't start at the same time with that fadeOutWithListener animation. Instead, they wait for like 100 or 200 ms then quickly (with duration of 100 or 200 ms) flash their transformation (coordinates are correct btw) and disappear. After fadeOutWithListener is done - listener's onAnimationEnd fires up and buttons become visible.

This is a final try - before I did without listener - just consecutive calls of startAnimation and setVisibility - was the same identical behavior.

Comment: use Scenes and TransitionManager

Comment: see how you can use Scenes with TransitionManager here: http://pastebin.com/u4TfVB21, when working with 4+ but pre Kitkat devices use backport library: https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport

Answer (score 2):

if you apply two animation to same ui at same time, as I remember, latest one will be performed.

to make multiple animation at same time, you need to use `AnimationSet`

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
set.addAnimation(fadeOut);
set.addAnimation(slideOut);
view.setAnimation(set);
set.start();
```

Comment: There's not a single place where I am (or I would need) applying two animations to one view.

Comment: sorry, I see some animation on onAnimationStart. anyway, they disappear because animation does not apply latest coordinates if you dont call "setFillAfter". set it true before start animation. for moving fast could be about "Interpolator". you can define how changes will be applied, linear, easeIn, easeOut. for instance, your scenario seems easeOut.

Comment: "they disappear because animation does not apply latest coordinates if you dont call "setFillAfter". set it true before start animation." Why do you advise to set me the parameter that I don't need to be set? They disappear (which is **NOT** the issue - please read question topic), because their animation finishes like 10 times faster than it should (and this **IS** the issue). Normally by the end of animation listener would set them visible and all would be fine. About speed: I doubt there is such interpolator that makes animation go linear but 10 times faster, I will look it up.